# Unable to see page loader image when ajax async is set as false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am showing a loading image before an ajax call and hiding it when the success comes.

```
$('#Search').on('click', function (e) {

    $('#loaderImg').show();

    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        data: '',
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {

            ...some lines of code

            $('#loaderImg').hide();

        }  
    });
});
```

When the async is false the image is not shown, maybe because the UI is not updated when javascript is executing.

When async set as true the image is visible before it is hidden in success block.

Please suggest a way to make the image visible before the success block executes keeping the async parameter as false.

Tested in Chrome.

Comment: Don't use `async: false`. It's a better pattern to use and solves your problem. Why do you need it?

Comment: does it happen that your ajax call does some intensive work? async: false means that it is synchronous by logical deduction and while the statement fires, it aught to freeze your page and all it's resources until the ajax call's job is complete, meaning between loader.show() and loader.hide(), it will happen so fast you won't see it

Comment: if another ajax call is dependent on the response of the first ajax call, why not call the second ajax method in the success handler, and delete `async:false`

Comment: Because you're freezing the browser and preventing user interaction, it's probably a *good* thing that the image is showing. At least it'll be clearer to your unfortunate user that the page won't work while the ajax activity is going on.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried global ajaxStart and ajaxStop events:

```
$('#loaderImg').bind('ajaxStart', function(){
      $(this).show();
 }).bind('ajaxStop', function(){
      $(this).hide();
 });
```

Comment: I suspect that this won't work. The "ajaxStart" event, if "fired" by jQuery as what amounts to a simple function call (which I think to be true), then it's effectively the same code as the original. If it's fired as a real event via the browser's innards, then the event loop won't run until the "click" event returns after the synchronous call.